# How to request enhancement to Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

Regarding Oracle's [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html) tool:

Is there a way to request that Oracle make an enhancement to the tool?

For example, I want to ask Oracle to add this functionality: [Generate WITH clause from resultset using SQL Developer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307095/generate-with-clause-from-resultset-using-sql-developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groundbreakers Developer Community: [General Database Discussions - **Ideas**](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/general_questions-ideas)

and Infrastructure Community/ Database Software/ Database Ideas/ [ApplicationsDatabase Ideas - **Ideas**](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/categories/database-ideas-ideas?sort=new)

---

**Edit:**

It looks like some changes were made to the Oracle Community in early 2023. If I understand correctly, some individual forums were eliminated and replaced by tags.

So, best guess is we need to tag posts in the **General Database Discussion** forum as `general-database-discussions-ideas`.

https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/3063-general_questions?tags=general-database-discussions-ideas

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Post it at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/sql_developer.  That's Oracle's own forum for all things SQL Developer, and Jeff Smith monitors that.

Comment: Thanks! I posted the idea: [Idea: Generate WITH clause from resultset](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4494489/idea-generate-with-clause-from-resultset/p1?new=1).

Comment: You might be interested in the answer that was recently provided in that post (can also be found here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307311/100880).