# How to request an enhancement to SDO_GEOMETRY / Oracle Spatial

Tags: oracle, spatial, oracle-18c, geometry

I want to suggest a few ideas to Oracle about  enhancements to SDO_GEOMETRY / Oracle Spatial.

Example:

Requesting a function to select vertices, including the **multi-part numbers** of SDO_GEOMETRY polylines.

[image]

---

**Question:**

Do we have a way to ask Oracle for enhancements to SDO_GEOMETRY / Oracle Spatial?

---

**What I tried:**

I found the following page: [How to Log an Idea (Enhancement Request) in the Customer Connect Idea Lab for Procurement Products (Doc ID 2577625.1)](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Fusion%20Applications/2577625_1.html)

But unfortunately, my personal Oracle account isn't “connected” to a my organization's Oracle Support account (I'm not in IT; and my DBA doesn't want to submit ideas on my behalf). So I can't get past the "Connect your user account" step.

[image]

---

[In a related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/307135/how-to-request-enhancement-to-oracle-sql-developer), it turned out that there was a way to request enhancements to a different product (SQL Developer) **right in the Oracle forum**. Which is great, because it's accessible to non-DBAs like me.

So I was wondering if something similar might exist for Oracle Spatial.

*And I'm not entirely sure if the "How to Log an Idea" page is the right avenue anyway. It seems like ideas might not get heard by the proper team...maybe there's a more direct way to talk to the Oracle Spatial team.*

Comment: Navigating to the link in the answer on your other question, it seems that the [SQL & PL/SQL category on the same forum](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/sql_and_pl_sql) is the right spot to submit requests for new language extensions or functions

Comment: @AMtwo Thanks. After some poking around, this is what I’ve found: Post general Oracle ideas here: [General Database Discussions - Ideas](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/general_questions-ideas). Post ideas about Oracle Spatial here: [Spatial Discussions](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/categories/3078).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post general Oracle ideas here: [General Database Discussions - Ideas](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/general_questions-ideas).

Post ideas about Oracle Spatial here: [Spatial Discussions](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/categories/3078).

---

**Edit:**

It looks like some changes were made to the Oracle Community in early 2023. If I understand correctly, some individual forums were eliminated and replaced by tags.

So, best guess is we need to tag posts in the **Database Software** forum as `spatial`.

https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/domain/dev-community/category/database-software?tags=spatial

---

[image]

---

Related:

[Was the Oracle Spatial Community eliminated and replaced by tags?](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/was-the-oracle-spatial-community-eliminated-and-replaced-by-7174)